# How to paginate data using zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, pagination

i need pager for my proj.

i found many different type of pager in the net, but i need to the pager that it be standard for mvc structure and zend framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean **pagination** then you should start with [**Zend_Paginator
Programmer's Reference Guide**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.introduction.html)